# drawing in canvas with mouse in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, canvas, mouse

I am trying to draw in a canvas using the mouse. My application works fine in firefox, but I cant achive it works in chrome. My code is as follow:

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

        scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width,    /*relationship bitmap vs. element for X*/
        scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;  /*relationship bitmap vs. element for Y*/
        return {
          x: Math.round((evt.clientX - rect.left)*scaleX),
          y: Math.round((evt.clientY - rect.top)*scaleY)
        };

      }
```

In the code above I get the mouse coordinates, for a canvas included in a div called "Lienzo". The CSS for the canvas and the lienzo is as follow:

```
canvas {
     image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;    /* Firefox */
    image-rendering: pixelated;           /* Chrome */
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background:white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}

#lienzo {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:1em;
    width:80%;
}
```

I have tried to look for a solution, but I can't because I dont really understand what is wrong.

The code that I use to paint with the mouse consists in an array where I push the coordinates and when I release the mouse it prints all the coordinates included in the array. Here is a fragment of the code:

```
this.mostrarForma= function(){
            for(var i=0; i < lista_de_puntos.length; i++)
              {     
                ctx.strokeStyle=color;
                ctx.lineJoin=tipo;
                ctx.lineWidth=grosor;
                ctx.beginPath();
                //If i am at the begining of the array
                if(lista_de_puntos[i][2] && i){
                    //Entramos aqui si pulsamos y arrastramos
                    ctx.moveTo(lista_de_puntos[i-1][0], lista_de_puntos[i-1][1]);
                 }else{
                    //If I press and I release the button
                    ctx.moveTo(lista_de_puntos[i][0], lista_de_puntos[i][1]);
                 }
                 ctx.lineTo(lista_de_puntos[i][0], lista_de_puntos[i][1]);
                 ctx.closePath();
                 ctx.stroke();
              } 
        }
```

I attach a fiddle link to make it clearer:
https://jsfiddle.net/ciberlook/rhwcbwwL/18/
Any help??

Comment: Can you create a snippet or a fiddle with the whole of the code that works in firefox? I'm trying to piece together what you have so I can help but I don't know what scope `this.mostrarForma` is in or what the mouse event you're using is.

Comment: ok, sorry for the delay, but I didn't know how to figure out fiddle, so it took me a little while. Therefore, I have attached the example in fiddle so that you can have a better idea of what is happening. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/ciberlook/rhwcbwwL/18/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution. In the code above the function mostrarForma() is fired in the wrong event. Here is the solution:

```
$('canvas').mousedown(function(e){
    pulsado=true;
    var posX=getMousePos(this,e).x;
    var posY=getMousePos(this,e).y;
        forma.definirForma(posX,posY,false);
        forma.mostrarForma();       

    });

    $('canvas').mousemove(function(e){
        var posX=getMousePos(this,e).x;
        var posY=getMousePos(this,e).y;

        if (pulsado){

            forma.definirForma(posX,posY,true);
            forma.mostrarForma();

        }
    });

    $('canvas').mouseup(function(e){
        pulsado=false; //I release the button

    });

    $('canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
        pulsado=false;
    });
    forma.mostrarForma();
```